# Can't get icon/input type to toggle with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm ripping my hair out trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want users to be able to click on the eye-icon and have their password show as plain text - but it only partially works.

```
init = {
    visible : function() {
        var visible = false;
        if (!visible) {
            visible = true;
            document.querySelector('#exampleInputPassword1').type = 'text';
            document.querySelector('.input-glyph-eye').className = 'input-glyph-eye glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open';
        } else {
            visible = false;
            document.querySelector('#exampleInputPassword1').type = 'password';
            document.querySelector('.input-glyph-eye').className = 'input-glyph-eye glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close';
        }
    }
};
```

I've put everything together in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lapxqz0/ - you'll see that the eye icon will change once, but the password wont change at all. It is supposed to freely toggle between eye-open and eye-close and type=text and type=password whenever you click on it.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?
P.S. I have jQuery loaded because Bootstrap needs it, but I prefer not to use it in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple issues here.

First, you need to move the `var visible` declaration out of the function, because it gets redeclared as false each time the function is run.

Second, the inputs for Authenticate and Sign Up tabs have the same `id`, which is invalid HTML and throws the JS off.

This is working for the "sign up" tab:

```
var visible = false;
init = {
      visible: function() {
          if (!visible) {
              visible = true;
              document.querySelector('#exampleInputPassword2').type = 'text';
              document.querySelector('.input-glyph-eye').className = 'input-glyph-eye glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open';
          } else {
              visible = false;
              document.querySelector('#exampleInputPassword2').type = 'password';
              document.querySelector('.input-glyph-eye').className = 'input-glyph-eye glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close';
          }
      }
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vtxLt2pp/1/